# How to Refer File created in Flutter MemoryFileSystem in Android Native code?

Tags: android, flutter, file, flutter-method-channel

I am creating. a file in Flutter's Memory File System and passing it's path to OpenFilex package's open method. OpenFilex package calls Android native code using method channel. So my code is failing.

How to refer/use/access Flutter's MemoryFileSystem in Android native code ?

I used below code to open a file to view in a third party app using OpenFilex package.

```
 String path = await AndroidPathProvider.documentsPath;
    var mfs = MemoryFileSystem();
    File file = mfs.file(path + "/" + "sample.pdf");
    file.writeAsBytes(fileData);
    await OpenFilex.open(file.path);
```